# Is it possible to build a Unity3D project with Bazel?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bazel

The majority of our code base is built with Bazel with the exception a few Unity projects.  Anybody know if there's anyway to build the Unity applications using Bazel as well?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not immediately familiar with Unity projects, but if the input files are purely C# code and `.dll` files, you can use the C# rules defined for Bazel. It includes rules such as `csharp_library`, `csharp_binary` and `dll_import`.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_dotnet

If these are not sufficient (special filetypes, using a different compiler, etc), you may have to write your own rules using Skylark, and possibly reuse the `rules_dotnet` rules for the C# specific code in the new rules.

Comment: Yah that's what I figured.  Unity is somewhat obscure on how they compile the code, so shall have to dig in.  Thanks!